# SQL Help Needed: transaction in date range one but then not in date range two for customers

Tags: sql

I need to create a SQL statement that will show me a list of customers that purchase a product from a particular product category for period one, say July 1, 2015 thru July 31, 2015, but did not purchase a product from the same product category in period two August 1, 2015 thru August 31, 2015.

Tables are:

```
Customers: custId, fname, lname, custtype
Transactions: transid, datetrans, custid
TransItems: transid, productid, itemdescrip, quantity, price
Products: productid, productcatid, productcatgroupid
ProductCats: productcatid, productcatgroupid
```

What I have so far is:

```
SELECT  Customers.custid, 
        Customers.lname, 
        Customers.fname, 
        Transactions.transid, 
        Transactions.transdate, 
        TransItems.productid, 
        TransItems.itemdescrip, 
        TransItems.price
FROM    Transactions 
INNER JOIN
WHERE   (Transactions.datetrans BETWEEN '2015-07-01' AND '2015-07-31') 
AND     (ProductCat.productcatgroupid=2)
```

The next part is where I get stuck. I need the query to then look in the date range of `08-01-2015` through `08-31-2015` and tell me if any of these customers did not have a transaction in that range after have one in the July date range.

Comment: Your `Inner Join` seems to be lacking in substance.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shows all the columns you were looking for from the July Activity that had no activity for the similar product categories by the same customer in August.  You were missing a bunch of joins between the tables to get to the final product category ID, and needed them at both the main level and the NOT EXISTS subquery.  I aliased the subquery with "2" such as T2, TI2, etc from the main query for clarification.

```
SELECT  
      C.custid, 
      C.lname, 
      C.fname, 
      T.transid, 
      T.transdate, 
      TI.productid, 
      TI.itemdescrip, 
      TI.price
   FROM    
      Transactions T
         JOIN Customers C
            on T.CustID = C.CustID
         JOIN TransItems TI
            on T.TransID = TI.TransID
            JOIN Products P
               on TI.ProductID = P.ProductID
              AND P.ProductCatGroupID = 2

         AND NOT EXISTS
         ( select 
                 T2.CustID
              from
                 Transactions T2
                    JOIN TransItems TI2
                       on T2.TransID = TI2.TransID
                       JOIN Products P2
                         on TI2.ProductID = P2.ProductID
                      AND P2.ProductCatGroupID = 2
              WHERE
                     T2.CustID = T.CustID
                 AND T2.Datetrans BETWEEN '2015-08-01' AND '2015-08-31' )
   WHERE
      T.Datetrans BETWEEN '2015-07-01' AND '2015-07-31'
```

Answer (score 0):

This Query will take user which only made a transaction during August and show if they had another one from July grouped by customer and product:

```
        select T1.custId,T2.productId,
        count(distinct case when Transactions.datetrans BETWEEN '2015-08-01' AND '2015-08-31' then T2.transid else null end) as Pur_Aug,
        count(disitnct case when Transactions.datetrans BETWEEN '2015-07-01' AND '2015-07-31' then T2.transid else null end) Pur_Jul
        from Transactions T1
        Join TransItems T2 using(transid)
join Products P using(productId) 
where productcatgroupid=2
        group by custId,productId
    order by custId,productId 
        having count(distinct case when Transactions.datetrans BETWEEN '2015-08-01' AND '2015-08-31' then T2.transid else null end)>0
```

I made the count distinct to show only 1 or Null.

Comment: They were looking for very specific product category which requires you to go through the whole hierarchy to the products table and include that in the entire sub-qualifying condition tests.